# Call JS events from native java code

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am creating a cordova plugin where i need to raise a custom defined event in the angular JS code.

For example I need to call the function below from native java code

```
var callFromJava=function(){
   alert("Call received from Native code");
}
```

Now I need to call this from my activity in native code.

**Update 1** Cordova file

```
public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    wv = new CordovaWebView(this);
    Log.i("PARSEPUSH","URL of main "+wv.getUrl());
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml.
    Log.i("PARSEPUSH",launchUrl);
    loadUrl(launchUrl);



   public void callJS(){
      //something goes here to call JS event.
   }
}
```

I want to use Cordova `loadUrl` and `sendJavascript()` methods. I don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void callJS() {
    if (this.appView != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            appView.stopLoading();
            appView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return document.location.href;})();", new ValueCallback<String>() {                       @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                    //doSomething for the return value
                }
            });
        } else {
            appView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(document.location.href);");
        }
    }
```

Refer this code snippet to see if it's help.This is not relative with Codorva Phonegap just call Js from Java side.

If you want to write Cordova Plugin,you may could refer [Devgirl's Weblog](http://slides.com/hollyschinsky/extending-phonegap#/).She wrote many excellent articles about the Phone-gap extension.

Comment: Also refer:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: thanks for reply. I implemented the above code. but the alert doesn't appear. the logcat shows `D/JsMessageQueue( 3765): Set native->JS mode to OnlineEventsBridgeMode`. any idea what is going on?

Comment: Which version of PhoneGap did you used?You could override CordovaChromeClient.onJsAlert to handle it yourself.Then equip it with the webview instance.

Comment: I am using Cordova 4.1.2 version. I got the issue with my code . the `appview` in my case is null hence not able to bind loadUrl to it.

Comment: please check the update code. I have `wv` as `null` as `wv.getUrl()` returns null. I need to set the Webview of it. and then use it in `callJS()` function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70202/discussion-between-inceptor361-and-chine-gary).